Android Local Server Webpage Help
Android newbie here, whilst I have a good understanding of networks. I’m not great with the Android processing on devices.
I am wanting to create a local webpage on one device, playing a looping video and then have 3/4 other tablets access the same video on the WLAN, is this possible?

May be an sync app that keeps all devices in sync regarding a local video file and a player app may be the easier solution and will save you a lot of WiFi traffic.
